Regression ad Dominance Analysis
I'm wondering if anyone can help validate my method on Dominance Analysis with this example:
I'm running a factory, making widgets and my processes are very manual (very little automation). Our production is based on orders from customers and varies day-to-day. One of my key metrics is Throughput per Hour (TPH) which is the # of widgets made / number of hours worked (total hours including direct/indirect workers). I have a productivity team who are continually improving processes to make them more efficient (Process Leverage) I also know that volume (number of orders) is my friend as my manual processes have capacity and when my volume increases I do not have to hire additional managers, supervisors, admins etc (I get Volume leverage).
So, TPH = # Widgets/Total Hours worked
I would like to know the impact of process improvement and volume on TPH. Firstly, I run a regression on the data (Y) TPH = f(xWidgets, xHours). As expected this yields 100% R-sq (Adj), Widgets and Hours are both statistically significant and VIFS are low. The results are somewhat as expected since TPH is the product of Widgets and Hours (TPH = # Widgets/Total Hours worked).
I then run Dominance Analysis that returns 70% Widgets and 30% Hours. So, I read this as 70% of the variance in R-Sq(adj) is coming from variation in Widget Volume (Volume Leverage) and 30% of the variance in R-Sq(adj) is coming from Hours (Process Leverage).
Is there anything wrong with my approach here? I can see that the regression may be questionable since (TPH = # Widgets/Total Hours worked), but the Dominance Analysis should be ok.
Any thoughts on this? Any assistance much appreciated!
